# why is one of two floated divs are pushed to the next line?

Tags: css, css-float

I have two divs which I want to place in one line, the first one with a fixed width and the second without a set width. If I try to set both to float:left, the second div would go to the the next line if it contains too many words. But if the second one is a non-floated one, it stays in the same line with the first div. Why?

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    /*if set to float:left, it might goes the next line*/
    /*float: left;*/ 
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">sidebar</div>
<div class="right">I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. </div>
```

Comment: At which resolution u are checked?

Comment: I've just tested the two answers below and the problem remains when both are floated left. The problem disappears when a matching width is given to the right div.

Comment: By matching width I mean something like left 20% and right 80% or left 250px and right 250px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second div is non floated the blue div will remain full width and only the text will float around the red one. Reduce the height of the blue div to better understand what is happening:

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    /*if set to float:left, it might goes the next line*/
    /*float: left;*/ 
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">sidebar</div>
<div class="right">I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. </div>
```

> The float CSS property places an element on the left or right side of **its container**, allowing **text and inline elements to wrap around it**. **The element is removed from the normal flow** of the page, though still remaining a part of the flow <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)</sup>

So the float element is above the blue div and only the text will wrap arround. If you decrease the height more the text will wrap to next line:

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    /*if set to float:left, it might goes the next line*/
    /*float: left;*/ 
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">sidebar</div>
<div class="right">I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. </div>
```

---

Now if both element are floated, the first one is having fixed width but the second one will have its width calcuated using the *shrink-to-fit* algorithm:

> If 'width' is computed as 'auto', the used value is the "shrink-to-fit" width.
>
> Calculation of the shrink-to-fit width is similar to calculating the width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm. Roughly: calculate **the preferred width by formatting the content without breaking lines** other than where explicit line breaks occur, and also calculate the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks. CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm. Thirdly, **find the available width: in this case, this is the width of the containing block** minus the used values of 'margin-left', 'border-left-width', 'padding-left', 'padding-right', 'border-right-width', 'margin-right', and the widths of any relevant scroll bars.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: `min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)`. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#float-width)</sup>

In your case the *available width* is the width of the container and the *preferred width* is the width of the element without any line break and we take the min between. If we have a lot of text it will logically be the *available width*

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">sidebar</div>
<div class="right">I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. </div>
```

If you reduce the content you will reduce the *preferred width* and it will be picked since it will be the min value

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">sidebar</div>
<div class="right">I am contents. I am contents. </div>
```

To avoid any *random* behavior simply fix the width of both elements:

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width:calc(100% - 250px);
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">sidebar</div>
<div class="right">I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents. I am contents.  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because left div has float:left style.. it will adjust automatically depends on window width.. Do u want the right div to next line. plz add this style.

**css**

```
.right {
 clear: both;
}
```