# Unable to break text on hyphen within floated element

Tags: css, css-float

The following image shows how I would like a set of nested elements to appear.

[image: desired layout]

However, the elements are actually appearing like this...

[image]

I've tried setting various `overflow` and `white-space` options but can't achieve what I'm hoping for. My best guess is that the `float` is causing the blue-outlined element to have no width and consequently there's no reason to break the text.

How can I fix this?

Comment: *My best guess is that the float is causing the blue-outlined element to have no width and consequently there's no reason to break the text.* --> this is called the shrink-to-fit behavior, you need to either add line break or explicitely define a width

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553829/8620333 (to get full explanation about the behavior)

Answer (score 0):

If the person's surname is long without any spaces then the blue bordered element cannot fit in the same level as of the left element.

To make the blue bordered element fit in the same level as the left element you have to give some width to it along with word-break property.

```
<div style="width:25%;background:#ccc;float:left;word-break:break-word">
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
<div style="width:74%;background:#ccc;float:left;margin-left:1%;word-break:break-word">
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```